# Prevent a keypress with an alert in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have an input field that prevents spaces. So i just want to add an alert to tell the user that spaces are not allowed.

I am sure i am being very stupid right but i cant figure it out.
My code line looks like this.

```
<Input id="filteronly" type="text" onkeydown=()=>{if(event.keycode === 32) return false alert('no spaces allowed')}/>
```

Sorry mobile keyboard does not have tag symbols.

It is just a simple one liner but it wont work

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend trying something less disruptive than an alert, unless its absolutely necessry that the user knows - and confirms by clicking the alert - that spaces are prevented. I would rather use a tooltip or some other message near the input to inform the user

Answer (score 4):

Your alert is unreachable, since you are using *return* statement.
The simplest way to reorganize your code:

```
if(event.keyCode === 32) {
    alert('no spaces allowed');
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move to `function` to handle keydown, and you miss typo `keyCode` not `keycode` as

```
 function keydown(event){
  //console.log(event.keyCode )
  if(event.keyCode === 32) {
     alert('no spaces allowed')
  }
}
```

```js
function keydown(event){
  //console.log(event.keyCode )
  if(event.keyCode === 32) {
     alert('no spaces allowed')
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="filteronly" type="text" onkeydown="keydown(event);"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `event.keycode` with `event.keyCode`. Btw, this property is deprecated and recommended way is to use `code`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys really helped. Lapskaus your comment is certainly very inviting. Do you have any suggestions on how i would implement it. I dont recall having seen something similar elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you-- ↓↓

```js
function someFunction(event){
  // if(event.keyCode === 32){ //event.keyCode is deprecated but if you still want to use it, it would work
  if(event.code === 'Space') {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents the space
    alert('no spaces allowed');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="filteronly" type="text" onkeydown="someFunction(event)"/>
```